# Looking for the title of a Lovecraftian story about faces getting torn off

Tags: story-identification, h-p-lovecraft

In the sixties I remember reading a story where a group of men are searching for an unknown, unseen monster who was killing people and destroying property. At one point, the men barricade themselves in a cabin/house while two men are looking out windows keeping watch. In the morning the watchers are still at the windows but it's discovered their faces have been ripped off.

For 45 years I've thought the story was The Dunwich Horror by H. P. Lovecraft. Today I discovered that it's not. I'm trying to decide if this scene is from a different story, Lovecraft or other author, or if it's an invented memory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story you are describing sounds like ["The Lurking Fear"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lurking_Fear).

See this part of the plot summary:

> II. A Passer In The Storm
>
> Traumatized by the disappearance of his friends, and by the disturbing shadow he saw in the fireplace, the narrator continues the investigation. He befriends another reporter named Arthur Monroe, and tells him of the things he has experienced so far. Munroe agrees to help him, and the two scour the countryside for any clues to the murderous creature and any remains of the Martenses. There is no trace of the evil family, but they manage to uncover an ancestral diary that had once belonged to them. All the while, the narrator has the constant feeling of being watched. However, they are trapped by yet another thunderstorm, and seek shelter in an abandoned cabin, where the narrator thinks back of the horrible events back at the mansion. As an unusually large thunderbolt clashes across the sky, Munroe walks over to the window to survey the damage, and the storm soon clears up. However, Munroe doesnt move from the window, and when the narrator tries to rouse him, he finds him dead, with his face hideously mutilated by some unseen horror outside.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks so much. I read The Lurking Fear about the same time as The Dunwich Horror and I guess I conflated some of the events and settings. I didn't look into The Lurking Fear because my recollection was that there was a single protagonist and it all took place in a single dwelling.